# Qt 5.3.1 - static building results in linker errors

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, linker-errors

I just built the static libraries from Qt 5.3.1 for Windows x86 with MSVC 2013. The second step is obviously a static linked application that uses these libraries. So I created a small application (just a MainWindow with some controls, for testing purposes). This is my *.pro-file:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = projectname
TEMPLATE = app

CONFIG += static

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

LIBS += -LC:\statics\lib\ -lQt5Core \
        -LC:\statics\lib\ -lQt5Gui \
        -LC:\statics\lib\ -lQt5Widgets \
        -LC:\statics\lib\ -lqtmain \
        -LC:\statics\lib\ -lQt5PlatformSupport \

INCLUDEPATH += C:\statics\include
```

Yeah. This is what I got from several tutorials/my memory from when I worked with 5.1. But when compiling I get those errors:

```
Qt5Core.lib(Qt5Core.dll):-1: error: LNK2005: "public: __thiscall QString::~QString(void)" (??1QString@@QAE@XZ) allready defined in mainwindow.obj.

mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: Unresolved extern symbol ""public: static struct QArrayData const * const QArrayData::shared_null" (?shared_null@QArrayData@@2QBU1@B)" in Funktion ""public: __thiscall QString::QString(void)" (??0QString@@QAE@XZ)".

moc_mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: Unresolved extern symbol ""public: static struct QMetaObject const QMainWindow::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@QMainWindow@@2UQMetaObject@@B)".
```

Does somebody know how to handle these errors? Do I have to link against some other libraries not mentioned above, or include some files? I googled this topic and found out that many people experienced the same problem, but they mostly use older versions of Qt oder VS. I also tried to export the project to Visual Studio (working from Qt Creator), but the errors remain.

Thank you for your answers :)

Answer (score 0):

```
QT += core gui

LIBS += -LC:\statics\lib\ -lQt5Core \
    -LC:\statics\lib\ -lQt5Gui \
```

You are loading both Qt libraries twice: default and custom versions. By default, QT contains both core and gui libraries... you must delete them manually:

```
QT -= core gui
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `LIBS`, `INCLUDEPATH` from project file and run qmake from static build on the project file to create makefile. If this will not help check your `PATH`